# UIPickerView set default select based on specific value defined in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I've created UIPickerView in swift and added array value from local storage called Realm. Everything is working smooth and prefect until client told me to set default select row in UIPickerView.

My concern is how can I set default selected row in UIPickerView programmatically when loaded from local storage. Here is part of my code.

```
private var pickerObjectView = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let pickerObjectView = UIPickerView()
    pickerObjectView.delegate = self
    pickerObjectView.dataSource = self
    pickerObjectView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    pickerObjectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if (textField.tag == 4) {
        pickerArray = timeRange

        /* Try to select 3 row in UIPickerView but not workint at all */
        pickerObjectView.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Please help me how to do it?

Comment: You have two `UIPickerView()` calls.  The one in `viewDidLoad` is shadowing the one in your class property.  Try getting rid of `let pickerObjectView = UIPickerView()` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: When loaded from local storage - try to put it in viewDidAppear, or place the line (selectRow...) right after data loading. Or edit the question and add more of your code.